# django middleware not working, but if i use decoration it works

Tags: python, django, middleware

running python 2.7 Django 1.6 this is my code:

## my settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'gest.middleware.RequireLoginMiddleware',
    'gest.NeedCnd.NeedCndSelectedMiddleware',
    'gest.NeedEf.NeedEfSelectedMiddleware',
)

NEED_CND_URLS= (
    r'/tab/(.*)$',
    r'/ric/(.*)$',
    r'/prev/(.*)$',
    r'/ese/(.*)$',
)

NEED_EF_URLS= (
    r'/ric/(.*)$',
    r'/prev/(.*)$',
)

LOGIN_REQUIRED_URLS = (
    r'/cnd/(.*)$',
    r'/cap/(.*)$',
    r'/tab/(.*)$',
    r'/ric/(.*)$',
    r'/prev/(.*)$',
    r'/ese/(.*)$',
)

#this is my NeedEf.py
## -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-
import re
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.conf import settings
from django.template import RequestContext
class NeedEfSelected(object):
    def __init__(self, orig_func):
        self.orig_func = orig_func

    def __call__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.session.get('sel_esercizio',9999) != 9999: 
            return self.orig_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            mess=" e\' necessario selezionare prima un esercizio;"
            d= {'mess': mess, 'redir':'/ese/', 'class':'wrn'}
            return render_to_response('generic_mess.html',d,
                                   context_instance=RequestContext(request))
class NeedEfSelectedMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.required = tuple([re.compile(url) for url in settings.NEED_EF_URLS])
    def process_view(self,request,view_func,view_args,view_kwargs):
        # No need to process URLs if user already logged in
        for url in self.required:
            if url.match(request.path):
                return NeedEfSelected(view_func)(request,*view_args,**view_kwargs)
        return None
```

when I access mysite.net/prev/ or mysite.net/ric/, url.match(request.path) results False, so NeedEfSelected isn't called. any help will be greatly appreciated.

## SOLVED!

Yuppie! I solved myself! my misunderstood. This middleware was preceded by another one. The first one, like this, had a wrong:
 **return self.orig_func(request, *args, **kwargs)**

it should be replaced by **return None**

because of the logic of the middlewares works with. In fact middleware are executed in sequence and **return None** when all the test passes, or an **HttpResponse** when you need to modify the normal execution of the invoked url. It was well explained in 
 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/
but I surfed it quickly

Comment: Did you check what you have in settings.NEED_EF_URLS? Did you also check that the middleware is called?

Comment: Many thanks fro your replay. *settings.NEED_EF_URLS* is that I am showing in my post; I guess the middleware is called, because if I put *import from pdb; pdb.set_trace();* between the two returns, it stops. That's bringing me to say *url.match(request.path)* results *False*